# Exporting C global variables to a python extension

Tags: python

I have to write a python extension to a C module that comes from a third-party package. The module contains the declarations of some methods and also of the following variables at the module level:

```
int mcnumipar = 13;

struct my_struct {char *name;
                  void *par;
                  enum instr_formal_types type;
                  char *val;};

struct my_struct mcinput[mcnumipar+1] = {
    "E0", &mcipE0,  instr_type_double, "4.94",
    "dE", &mcipdE, instr_type_double, "0.24", 
    "dt", &mcipdt, instr_type_double, "6.4e-6", 
    "coh", &mcipcoh, instr_type_string, "Rb_liq_coh.sqw", 
    "inc", &mcipinc, instr_type_string, "Rb_liq_inc.sqw"
};
```

I succeeded in exporting the C-methods to my python extension using the `PyMethodDef` mechanism as explained in the Python/C API documentation. Unfortunately, I failed for the global variables.

Is there a way to export those variables (mcnumipar & mcinput) into my python 
extension ?

thanks a lot

Eric

Comment: You can use [`PyObject_SetAttr`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_SetAttr) to set any attribute on any `object` instance(which includes the `module` objects), however you *must* wrap the integer into a python integer/long. This creates some problems when you want to set the value for the variable, since only the python object will be changed, not the variable used in your extension. You can avoid this using the python int also in the extension(and simply do `PyLong_AsLong` etc when the value is needed).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. Possibly the easiest way would be to create Python objects for those variables with [`Py_BuildValue()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue), and then add them into your module object (the one you created with `Py_InitModule()`) using [`PyObject_SetAttrString()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_SetAttrString).

If the contents of those global variables may change over time, and you want your Python code to be able to see the latest values, then you may be better off exposing extra methods which return the current values.

As a third option, you could use ctypes fairly easily to inspect or even change the current values of those variables. It would be a bit strange to build a true Python-C module for part of an API, and expose the rest through ctypes, but it might end up fitting your needs.

Comment: thanks for the help. The problem I see with Py_BuildValue is that I can declare some kind of constant value such as `PyObject *pInt = Py_BuildValue("i", 147);` but here what I need is not to create a brand new value but to fetch it from the third-party C file.

Comment: You can pass an expression to Py_BuildValue (say, `mcnumipar`) instead of a constant value. The linker should know how to reference those symbols the same way it did for the functions you called from the C module.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check Cpython functions:
PyModule_AddIntConstant, PyModule_AddStringConstant, PyModule_AddObject

Example:

```
 /* Adding module globals */
    if (PyModule_AddIntConstant(m, NAME_INT, 42)) {
        goto except;
    }
    if (PyModule_AddStringConstant(m, NAME_STR, "String value")) {
        goto except;
    }
    if (PyModule_AddObject(m, NAME_TUP, Py_BuildValue("iii", 66, 68, 73))) {
        goto except;
    }
    if (PyModule_AddObject(m, NAME_LST, Py_BuildValue("[iii]", 66, 68, 73))) {
        goto except;
    }
```

Here you have a complete tutorial with several use cases that worked for me: http://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_globals.html

Regards,

Pablo