# How do I expose a C variable to Python as a variable?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

Suppose in a custom python module written in C, I declare the variable:

```
static int module_state;
```

The functions in my module set the state of this variable. If I want to know the value of `module_state`, I can declare a getter function like this:

```
PyObject * get_module_state(PyObject *self)
{
   return PyLong_FromLong(module_state);
}
```

On python (3) I could simply do:

```
import module
...
state = module.get_module_state()
```

However, I want to expose it as a variable:

```
import module
state = module.module_state
```

I looked at `PyMemberDef` and `PyGetterSetterDef` in the API but I am confused about how to use them to expose the variable. Generally speaking I don't want the python user to be able to modify the variable.

The purpose of this variable is very similar to `errno`, and I want to make it available as transparently as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting C global variables to a python extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793353/exporting-c-global-variables-to-a-python-extension)

Comment: The suggested question seems to deal with constants, which I am already familiar with. However module_state can change during program runtime and I want to make each change available.

Comment: This is relevant (although pure Python) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can.

Comment: @DavidW yes I could use properties to work around it, but that adds two layers - an internal C ```_module``` and a user facing python ```module```.

Comment: Or a `__getattr__` function (if you're using a suitable version of Python?). I dunno if there's a better way of doing it

Comment: I believe that has the same problem as using properties. Since __getattr__ has to be declared in your python code while my module is written entirely in C.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I don't see why you couldn't define a C function called `__getattr__`. I'll give it a go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main suggestions in [Can modules have properties the same way that objects can?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880530/can-modules-have-properties-the-same-way-that-objects-can) can actually be translated pretty "easily" to C.

1. A module-level `__getattr__`. This needs Python 3.7. You just define a function called `__getattr__` using [the normal C API mechanism, `PyMethodDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef).

   This function would do something like:

   ```
   if (PyUnicode_CompareWithASCIIString(arg, "name") == 0) {
       return PyLong_FromLong(your_variable);
   }
   else {
       PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_AttributeError, arg);
       return NULL;
   }
   ```

   Note that the limitation (which I think you're OK with) is that variable would be read-only since there isn't an equivalent module `__setattr__`.
2. Use a class instead of the module. This can be a class defined in C, with [`PyMemberDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMemberDef%60) exposing the C variable as a property.

   This probably works best for a submodule (e.g. `main_mod.submod`). That way the main module could add your class instance to `sys.modules` something like:

   ```
   PyObject *sys_modules = PySys_GetObject("modules");
   PyDict_SetItemString(sys_modules, "main_mod.submod", instance);
   ```

   I think this way's probably much more trouble than the first option, but it would work in C.